# Change the author for commits with specific message

Tags: git

I have many legacy commits from maven plugin which use real user credentials.
I know how to find commits by email and change the author (short version for example):

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '
    OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
    CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
    then
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
    fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

How can I filter commits by a message that starts with "[maven-plugin] ..."?

Comment: (oh, some of this was in the subject) Do you want to change the committer email address, or the author email address, or the author and/or committer name, or more than one of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the way `git filter-branch` works is by *copying* commits.  It extracts stuff out of the existing, to-be-filtered commits, runs each of the filters you've supplied, and then makes a new commit from the result.  If the new commit exactly matches the old commit, the new commit's ID equals the old commit's ID, which means the new commit *is* the old commit; otherwise the new commit gets a new, different hash.

While all this is going on, `filter-branch` records a map: "old hash was X, new hash is Y".  Then it runs through the references (branch and tag names and such) to be filtered and, if reference *R* used to point to *X*, `filter-branch` makes *R* point to *Y* instead.

You can, in fact, change pretty much anything.  The tricky part is deciding *which commits* should get changed, and then *actually changing* the right things for only those commits.  In this case, you want to modify the copies of commits whose *message* starts with a known string.

The standard `--env-filter` is invoked this way:

```
eval "$filter_env" < /dev/null ||
    die "env filter failed: $filter_env"
```

This means it does not have immediate access to the commit *message*.  It does, however, have the commit's ID (in `$GIT_COMMIT`), so all you need to do is read the commit message and make your environment variable changes conditional on that:

```
if git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%b $GIT_COMMIT |
    grep '^\[maven-plugin] ' >/dev/null
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="new author name" ... # set exports here
fi
```

Using `git log --no-walk --format=<format>`, you can extract anything you like from the previous commit.  (If your `git log` command is very old you need the `--pretty=format:` or `--pretty=tformat:` spelling.)

For the set of things you can `export`, see [the `git commit-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html).

Comment: The first two paragraphs are the best explanation of `git filter-branch` I've ever seen.